# High-quality figures in html

Tags: html, svg, tikz

I'm writing the documentation for something using some tools that generate `html`. I would like to embed some high-quality figures into my pages that correspond to:

- font size and type should be the same as in the overall `html`
  content;
- fully vectorized.

All my figures are generated from `LaTeX` with `tikz`. It would be nice to use the same code to generate the figure for `html`.

I know that `svg` is supported by browsers but whenever I export my figure to `svg`, the font type and size are messed up even though I export `text as text` and not as paths. If the `svg` has `text as text`, isn't the browser supposed to print it with the current font type/size?

Is there another way to embed such figures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text should be the same size as long as they are defined the same *and* the SVG diagram is scaled at 1:1.

However, if your SVG has a `viewBox`, it will probably end up scaled differently, thus affecting the font size.  Even if the font size is defined in real-world/physical units like points (pt) or centimetres (cm).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vbYvU/1/